# Почему выделяется память только для одного элемента?

Tags: c

Выделяю память

```
int *A;
A = (int*)malloc(strlen(Text) *sizeof(int));
```

По отладчику видно, что текст есть и и длина текста немаленькая , вот только память выделяться лишь на 1 элемент.Почему так получается и как это исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что выделяется памяти под один элемент?

Comment: Что значит "выделяется только на один элемент"? Почему вы так решили? И о каком "элементе" вообще идет речь?

Comment: Что тут вообще происходит? Почему sizeof(int), какое отношение тип int имеет к Text? malloc выделяет столько байт, сколько вы ему сказали в параметре, и возвращает void*. Размер выделенной памяти в отладчике смотреть как минимум странно таким образом.

Comment: Отладчик просто показывает вам адрес (0x033a0068) и первые 4 байта по этому адресу, интерпретируя из как int (`-842150451`). Так как `int*` может быть и массивом и указателем на одно число, дебаггер всегда считает что это указатель на один int и показывает Вам ег о как адрес и число